# Why can't Java find my symbol?

Tags: java, variables

Java is giving me this error. I've been working for a while and am stumped. I can't figure out why java cannot find sum? Thanks in advance. :

```
C:\Users\Keegan\Documents\TwoNumbers.java:70: error: cannot find symbol

System.out.println( sum );
                            ^
symbol:   variable sum

location: class TwoNumbers

1 error
```

Here's the code:

```
public class TwoNumbers {

    /*** Class Constants ***/

    private final double DEFAULT_NUMBER1 = 10;
    private final double DEFAULT_NUMBER2 = 15;

    /*** Class Variables -- State of the object ***/

    private double number1;
    private double number2;

    /*** Constructor Methods -- Set the state of the object  double n1, double n2***/

    public TwoNumbers () {

         number1 = DEFAULT_NUMBER1;
         number2 = DEFAULT_NUMBER2;
    }

    public void setNumbers ( double n1, double n2 ) {

        this.number1=n1;

        this.number2=n2;
    }

    /*** Accessor methods ***/

    public double getNumber1() {

        return number1;
    }

    public double getNumber2() {

        return number2;

    }

    public double sum(double n1, double n2) {

        double sum;

        sum = n1 + n2;

        return sum;
    }


    /*** Transformer/Mutator Methods ***/

    public static void main( String args[] ) {

        System.out.println( sum );
        System.out.println("" );
        System.out.println("" );
        System.out.println("" );
        System.out.println("" );
        System.out.println("" );
        System.out.println("" );
    }
```

}

Comment: Look into variable scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sum` is defined as a local variable in the `sum` method, it has no context (or can't be accessed) out side of this method...

```
public double sum(double n1, double n2) {
    double sum;
```

Based on what your code is trying to do, you shouldn't be trying to access it any way, instead you should be simply using an instance of `TwoNumbers` to print the result...

```
System.out.println(new TwoNumbers().sum(1, 1));
```

for example...

Comment: And even if it could, nothing has called the method that would calculate its value.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis And based on the code provided, nothing should, the method takes two values and returns there sum, it has no need to maintain the result beyond the context of the method anyway...

Comment: Thank you! I got my code to work. Seems like such a simple problem, but I really couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Because the scope of the variable sum is only visible within the method you declared it in.

You cannot access a variable that is only local to a method you aren't calling.

```
public double sum(double n1, double n2) {
    double sum;
    sum = n1 + n2;
    return sum;
} // sum is no longer visible to anything else
// the variable was used and garbage collected within the sum() method.
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable "sum" is defined as a local variable inside the method "sum". Within the "main()" function where the error occurs, the only visible name "sum" is a member function. To invoke it, you need to create an instance and also use parentheses with parameters like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    TwoNumbers instance = new TwoNumbers();
    System.out.println(instance.sum(1, 2));  // prints 3
    System.out.println("" );
    System.out.println("" );
    System.out.println("" );
    System.out.println("" );
    System.out.println("" );
    System.out.println("" );
}
```